# best way to replace a string?

Tags: php

```
string '/home/adam/Projects/red/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg' (length=85)
```

what i need is just 
http://localhost/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg

what is the best way doing it ? i mean useing strlen ? substr_replace ? substr ? im a bit confused what is the best way doing this? becouse there is many ways to do this.

edit* there is no newbie tag :|

```
    // get from database red/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg
    $image_path = $this->data['products'][0]['image_small'];
    $exploded = end(explode('/', $image_path));
    $myurl = DOMAIN;
    $myfullurl = $myurl."/storage/".$exploded;
```

// it works!, but let see the comments maybe there is a better way :)

Comment: @sarfraz, no i cannot use it anymore :| even the best practices is gone, wonderwhy ? maybe they are lowering the database fetch load or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the image part:

```
$str = '/home/adam/Projects/red/storag/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg';
$exploded = end(explode('/', $str));
echo $exploded;
```

**Result:**

```
22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg
```

Now you can concatenate it with whatever eg:

```
$new_str = 'http://localhost/storage/' . $exploded;
echo $new_str;
```

**Result:**

```
http://localhost/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg
```

And It is most likely you want to concatenate the image path with your document root which you do like this:

```
$img_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $exploded;
```

The idea is that you explode the string with `explode` function by specifying `/` as delimiter. This gives you array, now you use the `end` function to get the ending part of the array which is your image actually.

Comment: wew, ive neverthink about that! . let me try :)

Answer (score 1):

If the path prefix represents your document root path, then you can do this to strip it:

```
$path = '/home/adam/Projects/red/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg';
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/home/adam/Projects/red/';
if (substr($path, 0, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) === $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) {
    $uriPath = substr($path, strlen(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/')));
    echo $uriPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if the string contains `/home/adam/Projects/red`, and if it does, you use substr to get the part after it, and you glue it with `http://localost`.

```
$path = '/home/adam/Projects/red/storage/*snip*.jpg';
$basePath = "/home/adam/Projects/red";
if (strpos($path, $path) !== false)
    $url = 'http://localhost' . substr($path, strlen($basePath));
```

Comment: @garvey: excluding the variables declaration, it's two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This one's pretty much the easiest

```
str_replace(
  "/home/adam/Projects/red", 
  "http://localhost", 
  "/home/adam/Projects/red/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg"
);
```

Comment: Though it's unlikely, you'll break the string if `/home/adam/Projects/red` is present multiple times inside the path.

Comment: @zneak Indeed, but that would be extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '/home/adam/Projects/red/storage/22ff0bc0662bd323891844f6ed342cce2603490ec0_tumb_2.jpg';
str_replace('/home/adam/Projects/red', 'http://localost', $string)
```

Comment: It's unlikely, but you'll get erroneous results if `$string` contains `/home/adam/Projects/red` multiple times.